# Node - Why is my gif so slow when using GifEncoder

Tags: javascript, node.js, gif, animated-gif

i want to render a Gif with [GifEncoder](https://github.com/benjaminadk/gif-encoder-2) ([older version](https://github.com/eugeneware/gifencoder)), but unfortunately the gif output is much slower or so to say, it lags. This is my code:

```
import GIFEncoder from "gif-encoder-2";
import fs from "fs";

import pkg from "canvas";
const { createCanvas } = pkg;

let frame = 0;
const size = 200;
const fr = 60; //starting FPS
const encoder = new GIFEncoder(size, size);

encoder
  .createReadStream()
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("my.gif"));

encoder.start();
encoder.setRepeat(0); // 0 for repeat, -1 for no-repeat
encoder.setDelay(0); // frame delay in ms
encoder.setQuality(10); // image quality. 10 is default.

var canvas = createCanvas(size, size),
  cw = canvas.width,
  ch = canvas.height,
  cx = null,
  fps = 60,
  bX = 30,
  bY = 30,
  mX = 10,
  mY = 20,
  interval = null;

function gameLoop() {
  cx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, cw);

  cx.beginPath();
  cx.fillStyle = "red";
  cx.arc(bX, bY, 20, 0, Math.PI * 360);
  cx.fill();
  if (bX >= cw || bX <= 0) {
    mX *= -1;
  }
  if (bY >= ch || bY <= 0) {
    mY *= -1;
  }

  bX += mX;
  bY += mY;

  encoder.addFrame(cx);

  console.log(frame);

  if (frame > 60) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    encoder.finish();
  }

  ++frame;
}

if (typeof canvas.getContext !== undefined) {
  cx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  interval = setInterval(gameLoop, 1000 / fps);
}
```

This is the output

[image: gif output]

I took the example from this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xDZa4/), where you can see, how smooth the ball should look like.

[image: how it should look like]

What I tried so far without success,

- Not creating a stream, when using GifEncoder
- Collecting `cx` in an array and use GifEncoder afterwards, but it seems the `ctx` is a reference object and I could not find a way how to copy it
- Playing around with P5 in hope, they have an internal calculation, when the deltaTime is to high between the frames

Can anyone help me here or give me an advice what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, I have already the solution. Setting the delay to:

```
encoder.setDelay(30); // frame delay in ms
```

Already smooths the gif:

[image: output]

My suggestion. Sleep a night and start with a **fresh head**